# Wordpress <?php the_content(); ?> without the "Read More" link

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I display `<?php the_content(); ?` in a non-single page without the `Read More` link?
Basically I just need to get the part of the post before the more tag as I have a separate Read More button with a `href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"`

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you either want to use

```
the_excerpt()
```

or

```
the_content(''); //'' tells it to have no text for the link
```